# Disable Switch to plain text editor in CKEditor

Tags: html, css, drupal, ckeditor

I want to disable the "switch to plain text editor" in the CKEditor apperance. [image: switch to plain text editor]

The only problem is that there is no valid option for that in the system settings in CKEditor so I want to disable it with CSS. Here is the issue. I can't display it to none, wont lissen to my rules.

Here is the HTML for the "Switch to plain text editor"

```
<a id="switch_edit-body-und-0-value" class="ckeditor_links" onclick="javascript:Drupal.ckeditorToggle(['edit-body-und-0-value','edit-body-und-0-summary'],'Switch to plain text editor','Switch to rich text editor');" href="javascript:void(0);" style="">Switch to plain text editor</a>
```

and I have tested all the classes and id rules by following:

```
.ckeditor_links a {
 display: none !important; 
}
```

I tested with `!important` just to make sure it will go with that rule.

and the same goes with the ids. Now I tested to display: none with all the a tags in the CKEditor apperance and it worked perfectly and the "switch to plain text editor" went away, so I figured it has something to do with that it wont respond to the classes and ids?

I find it intresting that it wont respond to this class but for all `<a>` tags it will? Wired?
Can somone try help me through this one?

Thank you very much,

Comment: "Switch to plain text editor" is not a CKEditor option. CKEditor does not display such text - it's some custom addition.

Comment: Then this is WYSIWYG module

Answer (score 0):

Since the id and class attributes are within the a-tag, your css should be:

```
a.ckeditor_links {
   display: none !important; 
}
```

for the class or:

```
a#switch_edit-body-und-0-value_links {
   display: none !important; 
}
```

for the id.

Judging from your explanation you do not need the !important flag.

Answer (score 0):

In case if You use Drupal CMS (this link is on Drupal systems)
The solution is pretty simple. Ckeditor has the option to remove this link. Go to 
/admin/config/content/ckeditor
find your text format in the list. press edit. Than find Editor appearance collapsed block end set Show the disable/enable rich text editor toggle